# jQuery - change content of label on clicking an input

Tags: jquery, text, input

I have the following:

```
<INPUT class="input_checkItem" TYPE="checkbox" NAME="n_checkbox" VALUE="1234" id="1" checked>
<label for="1">The value of this label is Yes</label>
```

And I need a way so that when I click on the `input` it changes the matching labels text from 'Yes' to 'No', and vice versa.
(n.b. that `checked` always equals 'yes' if that makes a difference.)

But I can't figure out how to actually access the text value, let alone change it.

So far I have:

```
$('body').on('click','.input_checkItem',function()
{
    txt = $(this).closest("label").text();
    alert(txt);
})
```

But this just comes back blank. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/v3wohg3y/1/)

```
$(".input_checkItem").change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).next('label').text('done');

  } else
    alert(2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click','.input_checkItem',function(){
    $(this).next('label').text('Done');
});
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/32/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

html

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chck">
  <label>No</label>
</div>
```

js

```
$('input[name="chck"]').change(function() {
    var text = ($(this).is(':checked')) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
    $(this).parent().find('label').text(text);
});
```

Next you can use html5 data attribute to set text because have text in js scripts is ugly.

Add to checkbox attributes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chck" data-label-yes="Yesss" data-label-no="Nooo">
```

and change js to

```
var text = ($(this).is(':checked')) ? $(this).data('label-yes') : $(this).data('label-no');
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4wsfvhdw/)

**UPDATE**

[JSFIDDLE_2](https://jsfiddle.net/4wsfvhdw/1/)

Comment: cheers, that's great. However, if I had two (or more) checkboxes, how can I Iimit it to just the one that has been changed?

Comment: oh sorry, fixed checkbox by name is bad choice you need be more global indetification like class etc. I updated answer.